# <noscript> tag not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've used the `<noscript>` tag to hide certain elements when javascript is not enabled; however, it doesn't seem to work.

My document declaration:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

At the end of my file I typed the following:

```
<noscript>
 <style type="text/css" scoped> #status {display:none;} </style> 
</noscript>

</body>
</html>
```

But the #status div is still present even after disabling JS. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I'm not sure the accepted answer of the linked question is correct. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript

Comment: @JamesMontagne the end goal is the same, but the problem is not.

Comment: Fair enough, I take it back.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Remove the `scoped` attribute of the `style` tag. It's making your CSS apply strictly to the `<noscript>` tag.

> If this attribute is present, then style applies only to its parent element.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style#Attributes

Comment: Thanks ! it works :) Don't know why I didn't try that. Will mark this shortly just when S.O. allows me (time limit)

Comment: Ah, actually I never used it before, but when validating my code with w3 days ago , it showed me an error (missing scoped att.) It was my first time to use this att. , I forgot all about it till I tried to disable JS today. Noob, I know :)

Comment: [100% w3c validation is at best not worth it,](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7940/139010) and at worst harmful (as you've seen here!). Glad to help, though.

Comment: But it only works on some browsers because they use the styles defined in stylesheets in `<body>`. But they shouldn't because that isn't standard (only if they have `scoped` attribute). Instead, stylesheets should only be used in `<head>`.

Answer (score 5):

A simpler to manage solution would be to make the element hidden by default and use this :

```
<script>document.getElementById('status').style.display='block';</script>
```

(or an equivalent class based solution)

Comment: Simpler, perhaps, but the `<noscript>` tag makes a lot of sense when you want to do something specifically when JS is disabled.

Comment: I thought of a similar solution (adding a custom class) but with JS enabled there is a short delay before JS load. This is important for me, so I wanted to handle it with HTML only. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @MattBall I upvoted your answer, which has the additional advantage of explaining the problem. I made mine as an alternative. Ahmed, there is no delay if you put this script at the end of the body, the browser doesn't render the page before it executes the script.

Comment: Yes you are right , I always used separate JS files. Also I'm using JS disabled to change custom cursors, etc. I know there are multiple workarounds here, but noscript seems much simple , less code for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `scope` of the `style`, like the code below.

```
       <noscript>
           <style type="text/css"> #status {display:none;} </style> 
       </noscript>
```

Answer (score 0):

@dystroy's answer is the right way of doing it, because:

- `<style>` elements can't be placed on `<body>` (except if they have `scoped` attribute)
- `<noscript>` elements can't be placed on head.

But if you don't want a delay, you can use the following in `<head>`:

```
<style id="noScriptSheet" type="text/css">
.onlyScript{ display:none;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
function kill(el){
    return el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
}
kill(document.getElementById('noScriptSheet'));
</script>
```

And add a class to your element:

```
<div class="onlyScript">Hello world!</div>
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/TQLfu/

Comment: technically noscript can be placed in head but when done so is limited https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_noscript.asp  "When used inside the <head> element: <noscript> must contain only <link>, <style>, and <meta> elements."

Answer (score 0):

I am adding this answer because this seems to be the most popular SO-question regarding the `noscript` tag.

It doesn't seem to fire at all with **"Sybu JavaScript Blocker"**. So in case you are testing with that JavaScript blocker **try using another JavaScript blocker**. When I used "Toggle Javascript" the `noscript` tag fired without problem. I did not yet discover a way to detect that "Sybu JavaScript Blocker" is being used.

---

My Testing environment:

- Sybu JavaScript Blocker, Version 2.93
- Toggle JavaScript, Version 1.3
- Chrome, Version 85.0.4183.83